# Windows 8 single page navigation using touch api

Tags: javascript, touch, windows-8

i hope someone can give us a guide on how to apply touch functionality in single page navigation for windows 8 javascript.

ive been spending hours in search engines but all i see are javascript based games.

thanks.

Comment: As per MSDN documentation I am able to find such an API for C++ but I am not sure whether such a thing exists for JavaScript. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh454883(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There's an incredible hands-on lab for touch in JavaScript in the "Windows 8 Dev Camp in a Box."

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29854

Without more explanation around what you're trying to accomplish, I'm not sure I can be more help, but check out those labs.  Touch input is the last section.  You won't regret it.